# Is it ok to do indexing of Mysql Table on timestamp

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have MySQL Inventory table of last 3 years which is very large and will get updated very frequently.I already indexed on few columns and it have composite primary key on two columns.This table also have last modified date column of type Timestamp("YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS").Now this table is taking lot of time to query.Is it Ok to do indexing on timestamp table.I looking for some suggestion what is impact if I create index on timestamp column since inserts are more frequent and any alternative is there.

Comment: If a specific index helps or not will depend on your query, so we cannot tell you if you have a query that would profit from an index on your timestamp-column. You could add a common slow query (e.g. one that you think could use such an index) and ask for advice. It should include: your table description (`create table tablename`), the query, and the explain output (write `explain` infront of your query, e.g. `explain select * from tablename`).

Comment: Your question is too vague.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (as it is currently), and the important (or slow) `SELECTs`.  We can advise on which indexes are useful and/or what new (composite or not) indexes would be beneficial.  Or you can study [_this_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) and do it yourself.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `fcinventory` (
  `fc_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ean` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tenant_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sap_sku_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `reserve_qty` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `source` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_updated` bit(1) DEFAULT b'1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`fc_id`,`ean`),
  KEY `index_fcinventory_event_id` (`event_id`),
  KEY `index_fcinventory_ean` (`ean`),

Comment: KEY `index_fcinventory_fc_id` (`fc_id`),
  KEY `index_tenant_id` (`tenant_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: This is my create statement

Comment: @solaflare i am moving this table data to HDFS by using sqoop my query is like "select * from fcinventory where last_modified_date>sqoop_last_run_date"